# Nashorn access Java object's methods

Tags: java, nashorn

I have the following code, it is class which defines bean, where RabbitTemplate injects when bean is created:

```
public class A {
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public A(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
         this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    }

    public void sendMessage(Message message) {
         ...
         rabbitTemplate.send(message);
         ...
    }

    public void receiveMessage(Message message) {
        ...
        invocable.invokeFunction("main", message.toJSObject());
        ...
    }
}
```

`receiveFunction` runs when we get some message in queue, it calls function `main` which is defined in javascipt code and loaded to ScriptEngine.
I want to be able to invoke function `sendMessage` from javascript code.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using `ScriptContext`

```
engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE).put("A", this);
```